# How to transform Soap object data using XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, wso2-esb

I have to transform following result using XSLT transformation.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
    <ns2:Response xmlns:ns2="http://urldata.com/">
        <return>{"accountstatus":false,"response":{"MessageData":"Test","Code":"99","errors":{"name":"Hi","code":"100"}}}</return>
    </ns2:Response>
</S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

And i Tried using below

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns1:TranResponse xmlns:ns1="http://test.com">
            <ns1:TranResult>
                <xsl:element name="ns1:AccountStatus">
                    <xsl:value-of select="//jsonObject/return"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </ns1:TranResult>
        </ns1:TranResponse>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
       
And Result Like This
<ns1:ResultSet>
     <ns1:AccountStatus>{"accountstatus":false,"response":{"MessageData":"Test","Code":"99",
     "errors":{"name":"Hi","code":"100"}}}</ns1:AccountStatus>
<ns1:ResultSet>
```

But i need is result like below,

```
 <ns1:Results>
   <ns1:ResultSet>
     <ns1:AccountStatus>false</ns1:AccountStatus>
   <ns1:ResultSet/>
   <ns1:ResultSet>
    <ns1:MessageData>test</ns1:MessageData>
   <ns1:ResultSet/> 
   <ns1:ResultSet>
    <ns1:Code>99</ns1:Code> 
   <ns1:ResultSet/> 
   <ns1:ResultSet>
    <ns1:name>Hi</ns1:name>
   <ns1:ResultSet/> 
   <ns1:ResultSet>
    <ns1:code>100</ns1:Code> 
   <ns1:ResultSet/>
<ns1:Results/>
```

Any one can figure this out please figure this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only able to use XSL 3.0 it's no problem. Just parse the JSON as XML and you're good to go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">


  <xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="true"/>

    <xsl:variable name="data" select="//return => json-to-xml()"></xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="/" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
        <ns1:root xmlns:ns1="http://urldata.com/ns1">
            <ns1:MessageData>
                <xsl:value-of select="$data//boolean[@key = 'accountstatus']"/>
            </ns1:MessageData>
            <ns1:Code>
                <xsl:value-of select="$data//map[@key = 'response']/string[@key = 'Code']"/>
            </ns1:Code>
            <!--- use this approach for everything you want to select ... -->
        </ns1:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See [Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyneU).

Comment: hi thanks for you replay i tried these substring method actually i do need other response separately. Example i need to get 
 `<ns1:MessageData>false</ns1:MessageData>
<ns1:Code>99</ns1:Code>
<ns1:codes>Failed</ns1:codes>
<ns1:code>100</ns1:Code>`

Comment: According to the change of tags on your question (XSLT 3) I just edited my answer.

Comment: @B Polit hi thanks for ur effect . currently im using (XSLT 1.0) when i change it to (XSLT 3.0) following error is appear `net.sf.saxon.trans.LicenseException: Requested feature (XSLT 3.0) requires Saxon-PE` since is there any possible way to do this using only (XSLT 1.0) or (XSLT 2.0) ? because in  1.0 version this statement  not working  `//return => json-to-xml()` if there has other way to process this ? because `>` sign issue.

Comment: @Rest, Saxon 9.8 HE and later are open-source and support XSLT 3.0 and XPath 3.1 with `json-to-xml`, so try to figure out whether/how you can configure wso2esb to use Saxon 9.8 HE, that way you certainly won't need Saxon PE and a license.

Comment: @Rest, if you want to process JSON in XSLT 1 or 2 then I would look into platform and/or processor dependent extensions to convert the JSON to XML. No idea whether wso2esb offers anything like that. I would guess there is also XSLT 2 or perhaps even XSLT 1 code somewhere on the web that achieves that. There is also a parser generator https://www.bottlecaps.de/rex/ that can consume a grammar of e.g. JSON and generate parsing code in XSLT 2 I think.